# Docker-compose tagging and pushing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few docker containers that I try to sync with `docker-compose` (currently are being run by bash scripts). I'm looking for a way to tag and push them to our ec2 based dockerhub (private server).

Using simply `docker` we did something like this (for each container):

```
$ docker build -f someDockerfile -t some
$ docker tag some <docker_hub_server>/some
$ docker push <docker_hub_server>/some
```

I'm trying to replicate this in `docker-compose`. I tried a few things but this one seems close to working (but didn't work of course):

> docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  some:
    container_name:some
    image: some:<docker_hub_server>/some
```

But when i run:

```
$ docker-compose push
```

I get:

```
Pushing some (base:<docker_hub_server>/base:latest)...
ERROR: invalid reference format
```

Any ideas on how I can tag and push my containers?

p.s.: I know that this is not the way `docker-compose` is meant to be used, but I also know it's possible and it fits my needs.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have tested this approach with Docker Hub, so you should be able to achieve what you want with the following configuration and shell session:

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  build-1:
    build:
      context: ./build-1
    image: user/project-1
  build-2:
    build:
      context: ./build-2
    image: user/project-2
```

(Here, you should replace `user/project-1` with `registry.name/user/project-1` if you are not using Docker Hub but another Docker registry, e.g., `quay.io/user/project-1`.)

The various fields involved here (`build:`, `context:`, etc.) are described in [this page of the docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

The `docker-compose.yml` file above assume you have the following tree (including a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and some [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) files, to comply with best practices):

```
.
├── build-1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── .dockerignore
├── build-2
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── .dockerignore
├── docker-compose.yml
└── .gitignore
```

Then do in a terminal:

```
$ docker login
  # → append the domain name of your Docker registry
  #   if you are not using Docker Hub; for example:
  # docker login quay.io
$ docker-compose build --pull
$ docker-compose push
  # and optionally:
$ docker logout
```

Finally, below are some remarks to clarify a few details related to your question:

- In your example session

  ```
  $ docker build -f someDockerfile -t some .  # with "." as context build path
  $ docker tag some …/some
  $ docker push …/some
  ```

  `some` is a temporary image name (not a container) so it seems unnecessary: you could just as well have run the following, with the same outcome.

  ```
  $ docker build -f someDockerfile -t …/some .
  $ docker push …/some
  ```
- Your `docker-compose.yml` example contained the line:

  ```
  image: some:<docker_hub_server>/some
  ```

  Actually, the image tags can contain `:` to specify a version, but not in this way (it should be a suffix). For example, you could tag an image `user/some:1.0` or `user/some:latest`, and by convention this latter example `user/some:latest` admits `user/some` as a shorter, equivalent name.
- Note that the full syntax for image tags is

  ```
  registry.name:port/user/project:version
  ```

  where `registry.name` should be the domain name or hostname of the desired Docker registry (if omitted, it will default to Docker Hub).

  This is mentioned in [that page of the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#tag-an-image-referenced-by-name-and-tag).

  So for example, if you use the Quay Docker registry, the image tag could be `quay.io/user/some:latest` or more succinctly `quay.io/user/some`.

Comment: All these commands use docker to build and push. Can I do it using docker-compose to push all the containers at once?

Comment: Sure: you can build and push the images specified in your `docker-compose.yml` using `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose push`, cf. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/

Comment: This is what isnt working for me. How do I push all the dockers that were built locally and push them to <docker_hub_server>

Comment: @NotSoShabby OK, so I've done some experiments and it worked for me. I refactored my answer to add more details (about the `.yml`, the commands to run, and the image tags naming conventions). Hoping this helps.

Comment: Wow this tip "some is a temporary image name (not a container) so it seems unnecessary" changed my mind! How couldn't I think of this by myself being so obvious? Of course removing the "tag" step all is straightforward!! Thnx.

Comment: I know this is an old post and I'm very late to the game, but this really helped me understand the essential concepts of how container registries and multi-container apps correlate. Thank you so much, @ErikMD!

Answer (score 9):

I added that feature in this [PR](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/9052)
And Once it released, you could use it as following

```
docker compose tag --template "myregistry.local/myrepo/{{ .ServiceName }}:v1" --push
```

Read more about this feature [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9051).

If this feature takes long time to release it from within the official repo, we will make it available in [our fork](https://github.com/ElmCompany/compose/releases)

### Update

Released in our fork : https://github.com/ElmCompany/compose/releases/tag/v2.2.3-2

Comment: I upvoted your PR, hopefully will make its way in soon

Comment: Alright @NotSoShabby . we will release it soon. Just we need to check why CI is failing

Comment: Ok! Congrats  ! https://github.com/ElmCompany/compose/releases/tag/v2.2.3-2 
FYI @NotSoShabby and whoever vote up!