# docker-compose: push all images to artificatory server using jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

How to push docker images created through docker-compose using Jenkins Declarative pipeline?

So, i have seen that `docker-compose push` will push to docker Hub, like said  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416685/docker-compose-tagging-and-pushing), by giving `image:user/project-1`.

Now , Jenkinsfile [from here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/docker-push-example/Jenkinsfile) as an example pushes single `Hello World` docker image .

So, How to write a `Declarative Pipeline` That pushes all the docker images created from a `docker-compose.yml`?

One solution I'm thinking is to push all docker images separately..

But do you have any solution to push all the images created from services described in `docker-compose.yml` to `artifactory` using `Declarative Pipeline` in `Jenkins`.

Comment: do you mean docker images not docker containers right?

Comment: Yeah...Sorry for making confusion..